# xfce 2nd panel underneath 1st panel that will lock to the border

Tags: panel, xfce

On XFCE 4.16, I have a horizontal panel that stretches across the top of my screen that shows time zones, as in this picture:
[image]

I'm trying to add a 2nd panel underneath of it, and I'd like it to lock to the first panel and when i resize my windows, they will be resized to the 2nd panel's bottom.  You can see in the pic that the window is positioned to the 1st panel instead, and underneath the second panel.

Is this possible?  I looked into adding rows to the first panel but I want the information from the two clearly separated and also be able to use separators.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go into:

Settings Manager->Workspaces->Margins.  My top 2 panels are 16px high, so I set the top margin to 32px.